# Docker Engine Swarm: Access Network from "outside" swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

I'm working with a Docker (1.12) Engine Swarm with two nodes running in a swarm "bundle":

- redis
- my node.js application

They are both connected through their own network: `docker network create -d overlay antispam`

I use redis as an in-memory database and I have another node.js application that is used to push new data to this database in - usually - one hour intervals. The data-pusher is a short-lived application that takes some text files, parses them and pushes their content to redis. There is [no "schedule short-running containers" feature](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23880) in Docker swarm, yet. So I need to run my application as a "normal" docker container and thus need to access redis from "outside" of swarm.

The obvious solutions would be:

- ... to make the redis port public, but that's also an ugly solution.
- ... to convert the short-running app into a long running one that usually just sleeps and just wakes up every now and then. Call me old-school, but I don't like to waste resources for just having a sleeping process.
- ... to use RabbitMQ or MySQL (available as services in my "non-docker" environment) as a data relay, write my data there and have the application in the swarm read it out again. That would add another wstep of work.

Is there any other option to access the network of those two containers from outside?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to access your docker swarm network from the independent container? I am struggling with a similar situation. Thanks

Comment: Ultimately I abandoned Docker Swarm as it was too much of a hassle for my small environment.